# помогите с расширением Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

подскажите как изменять css страницы на котором находится пользователь с помощью chrome extension ?

Answer (score 2):

Для модификации стилей страницы достаточно расширения состоящего из двух файлов:

`mainfest.json` (в нем описывается само расширение и указываются страницы на которых должно работать расширение):

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Sample content script",
  "version": "0.0.0",

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [ "*://*.stackoverflow.com/*", "*://stackoverflow.com/*" ],
      "css": [ "my.css" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Файл `my.css` (указанный в манифесте), задает стили, которые должны быть применены на странице:

```
#nav-questions { background-color: red; }
```

Данный пример делает фон ссылки "вопросы", на данном сайте вверху страницы, красным.

Answer (score 0):

Например: `$("class/id").css("display", "none");`

Comment: просили "расширение chrome". А в расширениях chrome JQuery обычно не доступен, так что функции `$()` там нет

Comment: Я так написал, потому что есть метка JQuery

Comment: Да, это автор вопроса погорячился. с другой стороны очень многие путают javascript изначальный и jquery и теги лепят за компанию

Comment: @Mike, разве в "расширение chrome" нельзя пихнуть `jQuery` через Content Scripts?

Comment: Можно, просто нужно его  1-м ставить, если есть другие js файлы

Comment: @Puvvl Можно. Поэтому я и сказал "обычно не доступен", а не "его там нет и быть не может". Только тащить целый JQuery ради изменения пары стилей, в расширение не лучшая идея.