# Изменить DOM любого сайта с помощью Chrome-расширения

Tags: javascript, jquery, chrome-extension

Как изменить DOM любого сайта с помошью расширения?

Допустим, я хочу при открытии расширения чтобы фон сайта, на котором я нахожусь, становился красным.

Comment: Фон и стилями поменять можно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/785289/194569   Если все таки хочется менять dom, меняйте на здоровье https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/776852/194569

Comment: Добавить пример на смену фона и можно ответы в ответы.